# Uncheck a Radio button in Javascript using the class

Tags: javascript, class, button, checkbox

Here are my 2 radios buttons :

```
 <input type="radio" name="sex" id="Button1" class="Button"/>

 <input type="radio" name="sex" id="Button2" class="Button"/>
```

When I call a function that countains :

```
document.getElementById('Button2').checked = false;
```

It unchecks the Button2. But I want to uncheck it by using the class

And when the function contains :

```
document.getElementsByClassName('Button').checked = false;
```

It does not uncheck the Button2

Why and what is the solution ?

Thank you. :)

Comment: Both buttons have the same class name, how you expect the code to work? You must give it something to distinguish the desired button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName()` returns a collection (like an array). So you would actually have to do

```
document.getElementsByClassName('Button')[1].checked = false;
```

But you can't be sure that your `Button2` is the second element in the array if you have more elements with class `Button`.

Answer (score 1):

you must iterate over the class elements !

```
   var elements=document.getElementsByClassName('Button');

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(element) {
       element.checked = false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a node list (which is like an array) not an element.

If you want to do something to every element in the node list, then you have to loop over it and do the thing on each item in the list.

```
var node_list = document.getElementsByClassName('Button');
for (var i = 0; i < node_list.length; i++) {
    node_list[i].checked = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an nodelist (kind of like an array of these elements)of elements of that class name. So you should cycle through it and change the checked status of each element.

For a generic approach (you can have as many check boxes as you like), use this code.

```
var allButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("Button");
for (i=0; i<allButtons.length; i++) {
    allButtons[i].checked = false;
}
```

If you are going to have only 2 elements, you can use

```
var allButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("Button");
for (i=0; i<2; i++) {
    allButtons[i].checked = false;
}
```

or

```
var allButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("Button");
allButtons[0].checked = false;
allButtons[1].checked = false;
```

Comment: It does not return an array. It returns a node list. You'll get errors if you try to call array methods on it.

Comment: @Quentin: Edited. I was just trying to simplify things. Anyway, edited. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `document.getElementsByClassName('Button').checked = false;` when it should be `document.getElementsByClassName('Button')[1].checked = false;`

`getElementsByClassName()` returns an array

```js
function unCheck(){
  document.getElementsByClassName('Button')[1].checked = false;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="sex" id="Button1" class="Button" /> 
<input type="radio" name="sex" id="Button2" class="Button" checked/>
<input type="button" value="Uncheck Radio" onclick="unCheck()"/>
```